# selecting all spaces in a text using regex in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

```
'John David    Alice Jack       Jim'
```

I want to select all spaces in this text. There are multiple spaces between David and Alice...and between Jack and Jim.

`\s+` doesn't work as you can see [here](https://regex101.com/r/oE8vV3/1)

Solved: It turns out that, I have forgot to add 'g'.

Comment: It does work, use `g` (global) flag.

Comment: oh that is right.thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use: /\s+/g

/g (global) All matches.